# How can I resolve error : Linq query cannot be translated.?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

@Karney. this is my code

```
             var customerMachineId = wcDataContext.Customers.Where(x => 
                     x.UserId.Equals(currentUser.Result.Id)).Select(x => 
                     x.MachineId).ToList();

               var customers1 = (from customer in wcDataContext.Customers
                                  join machine in wcDataContext.Machineinfo
                                  on customer.MachineId equals machine.MachineId
                                  where customerMachineId.Contains(customer.MachineId)
                                  select new UserMachineInfo
                                  {
                                      Mac1 = machine.Mac1,
                                      Mac2 = machine.Mac2,
                                      MachineId = machine.MachineId,
                                      MachineName = machine.MachineName,
                                      UserId = customer.UserId,
                                      UserName = customer.User.FirstName.ToString() + " " + customer.User.LastName.ToString()
                                      //UserName = (customer.User.FirstName + " " + customer.User.LastName).ToString()}
```

> .OrderBy(ti => ti.Inner.FirstName.ToString() + " " + ti.Inner.LastName.ToString())' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToList.

The error is given while querying data in jQuery datatables. I was trying to search data in a jQuery datatable. How can I rewrite this query to resolve error?

Comment: Given that this is a LINQ/C# issue I don't see why you tagged this with 'jquery' and 'jquery-plugins'. Please tag your question appropriately

Comment: Could you please try .OrderBy(ti => ti.Inner.FirstName).ThenBy(ti=>ti.Inner.LastName)

Comment: What is type of `FirstName`? Also it can help posting the full query (or better minimal reproducible example) and related entities.

Comment: @Kaivalya Mete, can you show the query code?

Comment: @Karney I have updated the code.

Comment: @KaivalyaMete, about your issue, I remove the `ToString()`, then it works correctlly.

Comment: @Karney. It displays a value as "0" when I removed that .Tostring(), The variables firstname and last name are of  string type and I want to concatenate the first and last name and pass it  to Ui in JSON format

Comment: There is no `OrderBy` in your query. Also, please tell which EF version you're using + database brand.

Comment: Entity framework core - 3.0 and database is Mysql database

Comment: @KaivalyaMete, try this: `string.Concat(customer.user.FirstName,customer.user.LastName)`

Comment: @Karney. it still gives me the output as "0".

Comment: Does `0` indicate the count of returning records ?

Comment: No. It returns me the number of users present in DB and their data but does not display the username in that , It displayes UserName = "0".

Comment: Still no OrderBy in your code. How can UserName be `0`? Is it mapped to the right table column? What's in the table?

Comment: @KaivalyaMete, can you share some captures, because I can not produce the error.

Comment: @GertArnold..Where should I use OrderBy? . In database I have names of users stored under FirstName and LastName Column.

Comment: That's not what I'm suggesting, but your exception is from `OrderBy`. How?